# How can i make that if i click the button the timer will count up instead down?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can i make that if i click on the button the flag will be true and in the timer1 tick event it will change the count and will count up. And if i click the same button again it will count down. Without resetting the timer just to keep from the point it was to count up or down depending on the flag. If True it should count up, if false it should count down. ( The flag is set to false in the top of the form ).

Now the way it is it's counting only back (down).

This the timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (hours == 0 && mins == 0 && secs == 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "Times up!!! :P", "Will you press OK? :P", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                textBox1.Text = "00";
                textBox2.Text = "00";
                textBox3.Text = "00";
                textBox3.Enabled = true;
                textBox2.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                lblHr.Text = "00";
                lblMin.Text = "00";
                lblSec.Text = "00";
                button2.Enabled = false;
                button3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (secs < 1)
                {
                    secs = 59;
                    if (mins < 1)
                    {
                        mins = 59;
                        if (hours != 0)0
                            hours -= 1;
                    }
                    else mins -= 1;

                }
                else secs -= 1;
                if (hours > 9)
                    lblHr.Text = hours.ToString();
                else lblHr.Text = "0" + hours.ToString();
                if (mins > 9)
                    lblMin.Text = mins.ToString();
                else lblMin.Text = "0" + mins.ToString();
                if (secs > 9)
                    lblSec.Text = secs.ToString();
                else lblSec.Text = "0" + secs.ToString();
            }
        }

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count_up_down = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

First, change the representation of time from hours, minutes, and seconds to plain `seconds`. Set the text in labels by dividing seconds by 60 and 3600, like this:

```
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

Add an integer instance variable called `step`, and set it to negative `1`:

```
private int step = -1;
```

On button click, change the sign of the `step` variable:

```
step = -step;
```

Now all you need to do is to change the code to use `totalSeconds += step` instead of `xyz -= 1` - and you are done!

Comment: What is the totalSeconds variable ? In the top of the form i had: int hours, mins, secs; so i changed it to what you wrote hours minutes seconds. But what is the totalSeconds variable i don't have it.

Comment: @user3667377 No, that's not it. Replace the hours, mins, and secs at the top with a single `totalSeconds`, and also add `step`. Use the expressions for `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` from the answer to set up the labels each time when the timer "ticks" (the three a intended to be local variables).

Comment: Show me the complete code how it should look like. Thanks.

Comment: @user3667377 That would be extremely counterproductive as far as teaching you something very useful goes (and I think that what you are going to learn from this exercise is very useful). Try your best following the directions from the comment, then post your changes to pastebin.com, and send me a comment with a link. I'll help you get it running.

Comment: dasblinkenlight thanks for the help. This is what i did so far with the changes in your comments above. http://pastebin.com/akArrLUi i'm not sure yet 100% is that the right way and still i didn't understand yet what should the variable totalSecond to contain ? totalSeconds is what i type in a textBox ? Is that the timer count ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateTime start = DateTime.MinValue;
    TimeSpan oldTime = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");
    tm = new Timer();
    tm.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);

 void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                TimeSpan runTime = DateTime.Now - start;
                lblTimer.Text = string.Format("{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}",
                                                runTime.Days,
                                                runTime.Hours,
                                                runTime.Minutes,
                                                runTime.Seconds);

            }
```

Hope the above code will help you.